# Core Data undo background thread deletion

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'm developing sort of a drawing app in which the user sets points on a canvas. What's being drawn gets stored as NSManagedObjects. I also enabled the undo manager so the user can undo the last drawing gestures by pressing a button.

It all works as expected.

Then I have a button to delete everything on the canvas (clear canvas). When pressed I make the deletion operation on a background thread cause it might take a while and I want to present a progress bar. Then I merge the background thread's model object context with the main thread's one. This works fine too.

But I would like to be able for the user to undo the complete deletion operation with just one tap on the undo button. This is what I'm unable to do.

For the multithreading part I'm following this tutorial: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

It seems I can't get this to undo beyond the merge of the two threads (it worked once, though, I don't know why). Don't know if I'm supposed to nest the whole thing in undo groups. I have tried but still no luck.

Comment: I believe you should be able to do it by wrapping it in an undo group and doing -undoNestedGroup. I haven't tested it, but I'd like to know if it works as well should you test it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying, but it doesn't work, it won't undo to the state before the merge.

Comment: Is the merge itself inside the undo group or just the background operation?

Comment: I tried putin just the merge itself and also the merge and the background operation, which is in another context, so I think it wont matter. Neither work.

Comment: ¡Oooops! Never mind, I just tried that again and now it works, I guess I had some other thing out of place. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but I don't feel I contributed nearly enough to qualify as an answer. I'm glad it worked for you and feel free to up vote my comment if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do it with nested undo groups. 
Wrap your operation and merge between

```
-(void)beginUndoGrouping;
-(void)endUndoGrouping;
```

... and use `-(void)undoNestedGroup` to undo.

Comment: That did the trick, more or less. What I did was nest between beginUndoGrouping and endUndoGrouping ONLY the merge operation (mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification). Now it doesn't matter what I do in the other thread that I can always undo the merge.